# Leaving company how best to remove outlook mailbox

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using *Outlook 2010*, using *Office 365* as the back-end. At the end of the week I am leaving the company and I want to clean my mailbox. My email is replicated to my own personal laptop.

If I use Outlook backup to produce an OST file, then reopen Outlook and delete all the mail, would that be effective? Should I set the archive option and archive every thing that is a day old?

My Goals are:

1. Backup my mailbox locally so if I need to access it at a later date I can.
2. Remove email content so its no longer held on the mail server. (I understand that our admin team can restore the contents if they so chose)

Comment: OST files are a cache of the server.  They require a connection to the server in order for them to work,  If you remove the email from the server then when that connection is made the OST is updated.  Use personal archive (.PST) if you want to keep your emails.

Answer (score 1):

Backing up your OST file will probably work, but it's more likely to work without any problems if you use Outlook's built-in archiving option.  That should also move the messages out of the live mailbox (and off of the server).

As you said, this only removes them from the live mailbox.  If there's a backup of your mailbox on the server somewhere (there probably is), then the emails aren't gone until the backup is gone.

Comment: A `.OST` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just backup your mailbox to PST (not to OST). You can use the free [Export Outlook Items to PST File](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookItemsExportPST) utility for this (set "Move items..." option to delete items in your mailbox after successfull export). You'll be able to open this PST with ease later.
2. This is done automatically if you followed #1. You can also delete empty folders after exporting your mailbox to PST with free [Delete Empty Folders](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderDeleteEmpty) tool.

Please note: I recommend these utilities because I'm one of the developers.

Comment: What are the benefits of using this over the native outlook client export option that is found in file, options, advance , export then to pick PST as the output format (Outlook 2010)

Comment: @JamesT, as i said, it can move items. In addition, it allows you to select multiple source folders in opposite to Outlook that allows you to select single source folder only.

Comment: Looks a nice application but I wanted to add this note

Although trial versions allow to test all product features, they have some limitations. For instance, each ReliefJet Essentials' utility cannot be run more than 10 times. Specific tools has additional limitations. To unlock all product features you will need a product key.

Comment: Why ReliefJet Essentials? Just use free OutlookFreeware tools.